# How to let "cross" pop up with ::after a different section

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a cross change to minus and pop up some text.

I have a example but I don't understand how it works with `::after`.

[image: Cross]

[image]

It is made with `::after` but I don't understand how to use it. Or is it made with a JavaScript?

[image]

My code

```css
h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-family: ProximaNovaT-Thin;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 34px;
    line-height: 44px;
}

h5 {
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 24px;
    border-top: 1px solid #777;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 75px 20px 0;
}

h5::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: url(https://d2311lpn2eqzan.cloudfront.net/villarealestate/images/plus-icon1.png) scroll no-repeat center center;
    background-size: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 70px;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 45px 45px;
}

.opencont h5::after {
    content: url(https://d2311lpn2eqzan.cloudfront.net/villarealestate/images/minus.png) scroll no-repeat center center !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


        <!--BOOTSTRAP-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- COSTUM STYLE.CSS -->
        <link href="Classes/Model/Contact.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

        <title>ThemeBuild B.V.B.A</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <h2 style="padding-top: 50px; padding-bottom: 40px; font-weight: 400; font-family: ProximaNovaT-Thin;">Contact gegevens</h2>
                    <div class="locatie-dropdown">
                        <div class="topc text-left">
                            <h5 style="font-size: 16px;">WOODSTOCK LOCATIONS</h5>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>

    <!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Two things; 1. please be careful with all-caps; it reads as yelling in some cultures; 2. Please include the code you are using, as a [mcve]. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide runnable code.

Comment: I'm sorry capslock was on Will use stack snippet

Comment: AFAIK you are going after an accordion. Try this -> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp. It has the same use case that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer what I can with the information you've given.

First, ::after is a pseudo element. You can read about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp.
This means that the "cross" (+) and (-) are positioned after a selected element (in this case h5).

Second, this functionality is most likely accomplished with some javascript. It would involve using an event listener (or in-line javascript onClick) to catch the onClick event of an element (in this case likely the parent of the h5 or the h5 itself), and change a css property that says whether the content is expanded (shown) or not. The content to be shown would be toggled on/off probably using display:none or visibility:hidden. The "cross" (+) or (-) would be changed appropriately within the same onClick event.

In pseudo-code:
If clicked, and content is hidden, then show content and change + to -.
If clicked, and content is shown, then hide content and change - to +.

Comment: Seen this code before. But that not the solution it should be. It should be in <div class="topc text-left"> after you use the cross it goes to <div class="topc text-left opencont">

Comment: ::after isn't a CSS selector by a pseudo element